# what is the bestpractice to find the index of a mutablearray send to a sort tableview?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, tableview

Sorry for that question, but what is the best practice to to find the index of a mutablearray send to a sort tableview ?
1. i create a nsmutablearray with a dictionnary
2. i create a table view with sort my array
3. when i clik on the table view, how to find the index of the origin array to modify it ?

Answer (score 0):

Set up the UITableViewDelegate (usually your view controller), and implement the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //the index of your mutable array can be found with:
    NSUInteger *myArrayIndex = indexPath.row;
}
```

If your view controller is a UIViewController subclass, and not already set up as the tableview delegate, do so by declaring it in your view controller's .h file

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {...
```

If you view controller is a UITableViewController, then it already conforms to this protocol.

Comment: thank you. i have use NSIndexPath   *myIndex; and then when i need  myIndex.row to replace information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Has this solved your problem?